# Geotools CQL to OGC filter

Tags: geotools, cql-filter

I'm trying to convert a CQL filter to OCG. I followed this example: https://blog.ianturton.com/geotools/code/ogc/2015/03/18/Generating-OGC-Filters.html

In line with `org.geotools.xml.Configuration configuration = 
               new org.geotools.filter.v1_0.OGCConfiguration();` I get

> "Incompatible types error: Required: org.geotools.xml.Configuration
>   Found: org.geotools.filter.v1_0.OGCConfiguration"

What could be the problem, since I'd say that the example provided in the link is working.

My dependency for that part is:

> ```
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>org.geotools.xsd</groupId>
>   <artifactId>gt-xsd-filter</artifactId>
>   <version>21.0</version>
> </dependency>
> ```

Comment: Try with v20 to see if it works, and if it does it may be related to the changes for the JDK 11 refactoring, see http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/welcome/upgrade.html

Comment: @IanTurton , that was the problem indeed. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a fuller answer if you want to use this code in GeoTools v21+ you need to change the imports to be:

```
import org.geotools.xsd.Configuration;
import org.geotools.xsd.Encoder;
```

and the dependancies to:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-main</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools.xsd</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-xsd-filter</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency> <!--for fes (filter 2.0)-->
        <groupId>org.geotools.xsd</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-xsd-fes</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-cql</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 2):

As @IanTurton mentioned in comments, my problem was that I was using version 21.0. Going back to v20 solved my issue.